# Unable to get has_many through working properly - incorrect object counts returned

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm still fairly new to rails, so forgive me if I'm missing something obvious with my issue. My current project involves users that are able to post, delete, like, and unlike bookmarks. On the user's profile page, there is a listing of bookmarks the user has posted, and another list of bookmarks they have liked. I've been trying to set up a more elegant solution to collecting the "liked bookmarks" instead of using .pluck like in the below code.

```
# inside users_controller.rb
def show
    @user_bookmarks = current_user.bookmarks.all
    @liked_bookmarks = Bookmark.where(id: current_user.likes.pluck(:bookmark_id))
end
```

Relationships for each model:

```
# inside user.rb
has_many :bookmarks
has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy

# inside bookmark.rb
belongs_to :user
has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy

# inside like.rb
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :bookmark
```

I received a suggestion to instead set it up as a has_many through relationship, like so:

```
# inside user.rb
has_many :bookmarks
has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy
has_many :bookmarks, through: :likes, as: :liked_bookmarks

# inside users_controller.rb
def show
    @user_bookmarks = current_user.bookmarks.all
    @liked_bookmarks = current_user.liked_bookmarks.all
end
```

Which makes sense to me, however I cannot get this to work (*liked_bookmarks not recognized as a method*) and I am unable to discover what it is that I'm missing.

I fired up rails c to try to understand the issue, and reset my user model and controller to the original code. When I type the following I get the correct results based on my database entries:

```
user = User.first
user.bookmarks.count # returns 4 (correct)
user.bookmarks.where(id: user.likes.pluck(:bookmark_id)).count # returns 2 (correct)
```

However, when I designate this into a has_many through relationship...

```
# user.rb
has_many :bookmarks
has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy
has_many :bookmarks, through: :likes    # <-- liked_bookmarks still failed, so I removed it just for curiousity
```

...here's what the same commands return now:

```
user = User.first
user.bookmarks.count # returns 2 (incorrect)
user.bookmarks.where(id: user.likes.pluck(:bookmark_id)).count # returns 2 (correct)
```

After examining the objects returned in the above 2 lines, they're *both* only returning the bookmarks that are *liked*.

```
# The 'likes' table contains:
t.integer  "user_id"
t.integer  "bookmark_id"
```

I'd like to return the correct number of objects as in my original code with the has_many through relationship using the liked_bookmarks designation. Can anyone let me know what I'm missing? Have I been going about this the wrong way?

I'm using Rails 4.1.8 and ruby 2.1.2p95

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second `has_many :bookmarks, through: likes` is overriding your first `has_many :bookmarks`.

To fix your issue, instead of `has_many :bookmarks, through: :likes, as: :liked_bookmarks`, use:

`has_many :liked_bookmarks, through: :likes, source: :bookmark`

and now you can call `user.liked_bookmarks.count`

More info on source in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18154959/2697183)

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you @AbM ! Looking back, I did have my logic a little backwards as well, this clarifies a lot for me.